# Debugging webpage for IE9 on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, web-development

I just realized I cannot install IE9 directly, as I have Windows XP. Is there some other way to debug webpages for IE9 on Windows XP?

- I know there is [IE Netrenderer](http://netrenderer.com/index.php), but it is just static renderer, I need to check dynamic functionality also, and I need to log in, which is not possible in Netrenderer.
- I know there is IE Tab Plus Add-on for Firefox, but this probably works only if you have IE9 already installed??

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your best bet is to install Windows 7 or Vista in a virtual machine and test IE9 there.

You can get a 90-day evaluation version of Windows 7 Enterprise here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx

And you can choose from a number of virtualisation products, like [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/), [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/) or [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).